# eth_estimateGas Error when balance of an account < the amount to send in a transaction

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, infura, web3j

I have used the following request to estimate gas in an ETH transaction in Ropsten.

```
## JSON-RPC over HTTPS POST
curl https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/YOUR-PROJECT-ID \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_estimateGas","params": [{"from": "fromAddress","to": "toAddress","gas": null,"gasPrice": null,"value": "0x9184e72a","data": null}],"id":1}'
```

But when the balance of the account(toAddress) is less than the amount to be sent in a transaction(**value**), the response contains the following error message.

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "error": {
        "code": -32000,
        "message": "err: insufficient funds for transfer: address 0x...DFCsbds807 (supplied gas 4010499)"
    }
}
```

The same request and condition in Kovan return the estimated gas.

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "result": "0x5208"
}
```

Is it necessary to maintain this condition (balance of an account > the amount to send) to execute **eth_estimateGas**? Though this was not the case previously. Mainnet also behaves the same as Ropsten.

Is there a way to work this when the balance of an account < the amount to send?